# Two way SSL authentication with .p7b file using openssl

Tags: authentication, ssl, openssl, pfx, p7b

There is a server which we need to integrate with and our system is client consuming other service.  Other service wants to use two-way ssl authentication and they shared a .p7b file with us. After installing certificates into our windows platform we were still not able to access to their services.

As my research, p7b files dont contain any private key although in two way ssl authentication need to use same cert and private key in each side.

I dont how how much this make sense but,
I checked the cert and I see it is using 2048 bit encryption

and I convert p7b file to cert

```
openssl pkcs7 -in provided_cert.p7b -print_certs -out certs.pem
```

and I generated privatekey.pem  2048 as follows

```
openssl genrsa -out myKey.pem 2048
```

and try to generate p12 file with

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out keyStore.p12 -inkey myKey.pem -in certs.pem
```

but it occurs error like

```
No certificate matches private key
```

there are lots of cert formats , key generators and other implementation details etc and I lost into them.
Could you clarify this situation ? 
Thanks.

Comment: Your title is misleading, your problem is how to create a p12 file using openssl, not the ssl authentication.

Comment: thanks @Robert I updated the title as you recommended. I hope you can give some tips about my problem.